# Enhanced Ecommerce List Attribution don't work with Measurement Protocol HTTP Request

Tags: google-analytics, measurement, measurement-protocol

I'm sending Enhanced Ecommerce Purchase events through Measurement Protocol HTTP Requests and the Enhanced Ecommerce Reports are being populated with the exception of the Product List Performance. Investigating I found out that all hits are being attributed to Returning Users, but comparing with my Prod View I know that at least 40% are from New Users.
I'm sending Queue Time Parameter and I supposed that the hit would be attached to the preview session, but it's not.

My hits are built through GA's raw data storage in Bigquery. I have a checkout-success event from which I get the clientId and the hit time. I cross this data with our internal purchase data and then build the request and send it. Briefly.

My hit have the parameters bellow:

```
&v          =   1
&t          =   'event'
&tid        =   'UA-XXXXXX'
&ni         =   1
&de         =   'UTF-8'
&cid        =   clientId
&uid        =   id_sso
&cn         =   campaign
&cm         =   medium
&cs         =   source
&ds         =   DeviceType
&dl         =   DocumentLocationURL 
&dt         =   PageTitle
&ul         =   locale_ul
&cd78       =   1
&cd80       =   'bigquery'
&ec         =   'Ecommerce MP'
&ea         =   'Purchase MP'
&pa         =   'purchase'
&ti         =   order_id
&tr         =   OperatingIncome
&cu         =   currency_sold
&pr1id      =   skuGeneric
&pr1nm      =   OfferTitleExhibition
&pr1va      =   offer_option_id
&pr1qt      =   offer_option_qty_dailies
&pr1pr      =   UnitPrice
&pr1ca      =   Categories
&qt         =   qt
```

I already compared the data I'm sending to validate the time limitations of Queue Time and the time difference between the original hit and the measurement hit is not the problem.

What I'm missing to not get the List Attribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it looks like you're sending UTC timestamp value as `qt` parameter instead of sending a time delta (in milliseconds) value.
Second, you don't need to send campaign/source/medium parameters if you're not going to assign this hit to a particular campaign.

Comment: Hi! hitTimeUTC actually is just the name of the first variable that I'm assigning, after this step, I make some actions to let the qt as timestamp before sending the request. I forgot to change the name in the post. We'll use this data to make campaign analysis, so these parameters are important to us. 
I made some advance after this publication, I think my problem is related to the queue time but because my DAG is sending the request with a very long delay. I'm waiting to get some results of the modification of the DAG to write an update.

Comment: Hi! I found out that I was sending the qt parameter as seconds instead of milliseconds, so I'll mark your question as the right solution. Thanks. (: